# Displaying all of my table values in individual fields using crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm new to CR. I just want to ask something.

Hyphotetically, Can I display all of my table data as individual fields? I need to do this based on what value is in my table,

For example;

I have a table that can store name and amount in their value fields

```
Name         |  Amount

Smith        |  100
Will         |  200
Pedro        |  300
```

Using crystal report, I want that value to be formatted like;

```
     Name

Smith |  Will  | Pedro

100   |  200   | 300
```

Basically, I want to put the value of amount below name and transform "NAME" to the header.

Can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: YES YOU CAN. if you're using the designer, then it's a matter of setting up the datasource, and then drag-and-drop the fields.

Comment: I am using the designer, and already set my data source. tried dragging the fields but when I preview it, all the data are vertical just like what the first table displays.

Comment: Just rearrange the fields, and make sure they're in the drilldown section

Answer (score 0):

Use ***Insert, CrossTab...***

Set no rows. Set Columns to be the Name. Set the value to be the Amount.